# Can I override a class type with a plugin that creates a type of the same name but different?

Tags: c++, plugins, dll, factory

> ```
> Language: C++;
> Platform: Win32;
> Tool: Visual Studio 2012;
> ```

I have created a list of factories that can return different interfaces. Also a list of .dll plugin factories. What will happen if a plugin factory returns an interface to a concrete type created within it's .dll of the same class name as the main project? Will it override it/create it instead?

OK **please try and imagine this pseudo-code**:

```
// Inside CFactoryGeometryPlugin_Sphere.dll
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
IFactory* CFactoryGeometryPlugin_Sphere::CreateClassInstance(void)
{
    return (new CGeometrySphere());
}

// Also Inside CFactoryGeometryPlugin_Sphere.dll
class CGeometrySphere : public IGeometry
{
    // stuff here
    void SomeDifferentFunction(void);
};
```

then...

```
// Inside the main project:
class CGeometrySphere : IGeometry
{
    // stuff here
    void Function_A(void);
};

class CFactoryManager
{
    // stuff here
    template<typename FactoryT>
    void CreateAndRegisterTypes(int iType);

    unordered_map<int, IFactory> m_umapFactories;
};

template<typename FactoryT>
CFactoryManager::CreateAndRegisterType(int iType)
{
    umapFactories[iType] = new FactoryT;
}
```

so now...

```
// From main project this is ok I understand will create CGeometrySphere from main project
m_FactoryManager.CreateAndRegisterType<CGeometrySphere>(/*MyCodeHere*/);
```

But what happens here...?

```
// From CPluginManager in EXE.
CreateAndRegisterType<CFactoryGeometryPlugin_Sphere>();

// Then call the create function to create the class
umapFactories[iType] = /*Plugin*/->GetFunctionPtr<fpCreateFactoryObject_T>("CreateClassInstance");

// Basically the new is called from within the dll instead of the main project
```

**Edit* Clarification:
There is also a CPluginManager contained in CFactoryManager. It takes the this pointer of CFactoryManager. It is how it is able to access umapFactories.

I know I could have just made the original CGeometrySphere a .dll and just replace the .dll with another to override it - but that's the easy way! Is it possible to do the way I asked? Many thanks.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear for me what you're actually asking. Is it, you want to provide a replacement implementation for `CGeometrySphere` from your application? If not, isn't that just the whole purpose of plugins, to just hand out your private implementation of an interface? Do you have got any errors when you tried that stuff shown in your question, if so wich ones exactly. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: `CreateClassInstance` won't compile - `CGeometrySphere*` is not convertible to `IFactory*`. Did you mean to derive the former from the latter?

Comment: How did `m_FactoryManager` make it to the DLL? Does the DLL contain its own, unrelated implementation of `CFactoryManager` and declares its own variable named `m_FactoryManager`? If so, `m_FactoryManager` in the EXE and `m_FactoryManager` in the DLL are completely separate - just like `CGeometrySphere` in the EXE and `CGeometrySphere` in the DLL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have edited out the m_FactoryManager being in the dll. The dll only creates the CGeometrySphere.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ sorry I have tried to summerise my code as it is too much to place it all here.

Comment: `But what happens here...?` Nothing myserious. `m_FactoryManager.umapFactories[iType]` is assigned an `IFactory*` pointer returned by the DLL. The fact that the dynamic type of the object behind this pointer was known, when the DLL was compiled, by some name that also happened to be used by the EXE for an unrelated class, is irrelevant. Nothing in your setup relies on, or cares about, the names being the same, or different.